# Why does VS2012 run identical tests at different speeds?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, visual-studio-2012, performance-testing

I'm working on a project at work where there's a performance issue with the code.

I've got some changes I think will improve performance, but no real way of gauging how my changes affect it.

I wrote a unit test that does things the way they're currently implemented, with a `Stopwatch` to monitor how fast the function runs. I've also wrote a similar unit test that does things slightly differently.

If the tests are ran together, one takes 1s to complete, the other takes 73 ms.
If the tests are ran separately, they both take around 1s to complete (yea.. that change i made didn't seem to change much).

If the tests are identical, I have the same issue, one runs faster than the other.

Is visual studio doing something behind the scenes to improve performance? Can I turn it off if it is?

I've tried moving tests into different files, which didn't fix the issue I'm having.

I'd like to be able to run all the tests, but have them run as if there's only one test running at a time.

Comment: I think that depents on the code. You need to initialze some classes, which is done in the second test.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that the FIRST test always runs faster than the second, and I'd also be willing to bet that it's because there is some setup required, which the first test does, and the second test does not need to redo.

Comment: If you are running in the debugger, or in debug built assemblies, or using the profiler API (Moles) there are no times you can depend on.

Comment: Standard answer: use a profiler.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess: it's likely down to dll loading and JIT compiling

#### 1. Assembly loading.

.NET lazily loads assemblies (dll's). If you add reference to FooLibrary, it doesn't mean it gets loaded when your code loads.
Instead, what happens is that the first time you call a function or instantiate a class from FooLibrary, *then* the CLR will go and load the dll it lives in. This involves searching for it in the filesystem, possible security checks, etc.
If your code is even moderately complex, then the "first test" can often end up causing dozens of assemblies to get loaded, which obviously takes some time.
Subsequent tests appear fast because everything's already loaded.

#### 2. JIT Compiling

Remember, your .NET assemblies don't contain code that the CPU can directly execute. Whenever you call any .NET function, the CLR takes the MSIL bytecode and compiles it into executable machine code, and then it goes and runs this machine code. It does this on a per-function basis.
So, if you consider that the first time you call *any* function, there will be a small delay while it JIT compiles, these things can add up. This can be particularly bad if you're calling a lot of functions or initializing a big third party library (think entity framework, etc).
As above, subsequent tests appear fast, because many of the functions will have already been JIT compiled, and cached in memory.

#### So, how can you get around this?

You can improve the assembly loading time by having fewer assemblies. This means fewer file searches and so on. [The microsoft .NET performance guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647790.aspx) go into more detail.
Also, I believe installing them in the global assembly cache may (??) help, but I haven't tested that at all so please take it with a large grain of salt.
Installing into the GAC requires administrative permissions and is quite a heavyweight operation. You don't want to be doing it during development, as it *will* cause you problems (assemblies get loaded from the GAC in preference to the filesystem, so you can end up loading old copies of your code without realizing it).

You can improve the JIT time by using [ngen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to pre-compile your assemblies. However, like with the GAC, this requires administrative permissions and takes some time, so you do not want to do it during development either.

My advice?

Firstly, measuring performance in unit tests is not a particularly good or reliable thing to be doing. Who knows what else visual studio is doing in the background that may or may not affect your tests.

Once you've got your code you're trying to benchmark out into a standalone app, have it loop and run all the tests twice, and discard the first result :-)

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed explanation! I didn't know about Assembly Loading and JIT Compiling, or how the two worked! - This really made sense! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

"Premature optimization is the root of all evil."

If you didn't measure before, how do you know you are fixing anything now? How do you even know you had a problem that needed to be solved?

Unit tests are for operational correctness. They could be used for performance, but I would not depend on that because many other factors come into play at run-time.

Your best bet is to get a profiler (or use one that comes with VS) and start measuring.

Comment: We have had an application out for a while, under load there's now delays. I've ran a SQL profiler and saw that it's hitting the database multiple times, I can stop it doing that by changing the nhibernate fetch mode to join.. There's also a really odd abstraction over the top of NH that I think I can remove, which will also improve performance.. That's why I wanted to check the times between the old and new functions. - the problem is I need to be able to say to my boss this is roughly the improvement we will gain, if i'm given the time to do this work (as it's a big refactor)

Comment: Your first two lines do not address the OP.  They are also contradictory to the information already provided.

Comment: @Trisped - who is the comment directed at?

Comment: @StingyJack it is direct at you (since I did not have @ Jamez).  I was trying to politely indicate that your answer would be better without the first two lines.

Comment: @Trisped - But its not, because performance measurement is at the heart of the problem. OP refactors code to make it work "better", but admittedly did not measure the actual prior condition before making the change (wrote a unit test that did something similar). Then wants to improve it and know that it is more performant, but using the same incorrect (albeit a somewhat analogous) measuring stick. I will agree that there are some blatant things that can improve performance, but if OP is at this level of trial, its probably not blatant.

Comment: @StingyJack - Profilers have been used and optimization does need to take place. We used SQL profilers to measure before, so we run them again after the new component has been injected. Unit tests are just being used to execute certain components so that we can profile them. The SW was just to see how long it took to init the NHSessionFactory as one component was doing it several times (contractor did that). I was just curious as to why small/empty tests ran faster than others that were identical, depending on their order. And if it'd have much of an impact (turns out it wont).

Comment: No, first using the SQL profiler to see what SQL statements were being executed and if they could be improved/reduced. Secondly and separately, using a unit test to execute the component that caused the SQL to be executed to see if changing the dependency responsible for mapping / factory instantiation helped improve the time which the function executed in. It was just curiosity when running two almost empty tests that sparked the question.